# Issues with h2 upgrade to 1.2.147 - getNString exception

Tags: java, database, h2

I have recently upgraded to h2 1.2.147. My code throws an exception - 
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getNString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Any idea?

Thanks,
Anuprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your .jar file was not compiled with support for Java6 (i.e. JDBC4)

There is a pre-processor directive in the source code that only compiles that method when you compile it with Java6

Try re-building it with Java6, then the method should be there

Comment: It is true that the default h2 jar file is compiled for Java 5, and does not contain the method getNString.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think this will work. But as of now I am unable to compile h2.jar. Getting this error - Downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.4/servlet-api-2.4.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error downloading

Comment: @Anuprit: are you connected to the internet on the computer where your compile h2?

Comment: I am connected to internet. But it was failing to download. Now I have copied those jars to ./ext as said by Thomas and the h2.jar got compiled. Now, I can try it for getNString error.